# Hide section* from sidebar

Tags: beamer

I'm creating a beamer presentation but I have an unsolved problem:
I wanted Introduction and Conclusion sections before and after the core of my presentation.
I wanted them unnumbered (`\section*`} but they still appear on the sidebar and take 2 lines on each frame...

I have also tried `\section*[]{}` that displays a "[" in the sidebar...

Edit: The structure of the document:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    \section*{Introduction}

    \begin{frame}{Introduction}

    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Outline}
        \tableofcontents[pausesections]
    \end{frame}

    \section{Context}
    % Slides of Context section
    \section{Development}
    % Slides of Development section
    \section{Results}
    % Slides of Development section

    \section*{Conclusion}

    \begin{frame}{Conclusion}

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The idea is hide the Introduction and Conclusion sections from the side bar

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you show us a compilable minimal example? Without knowing what theme etc you are using, it's hard to guess a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and sorry for not have been as precise as needed.
Edition including code is done :)

Answer (score 7):

This problem is two-folded:

1) removing the introduction is already covered in [alwaysask](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/317796/36296)s answer, just don't use any section `\section{}` which will not show up in the headline.

2) With the conclusion it is a bit different. If you don't use a section, it will automatically be part of the previous section. To prevent this, you can place an empty section `\section{}`

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Introduction}

    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Outline}
        \tableofcontents[pausesections]
    \end{frame}

    \section{Context}
    % Slides of Context section
    \section{Development}
    % Slides of Development section
    \section{Results}
    \frame{}
    % Slides of Development section
        \section{}
    \begin{frame}{Conclusion}

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

## EDIT 2018

The above solution no longer works with the current version of beamer, use the following code instead:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\makeatletter
\let\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson=\beamer@writeslidentry%
\def\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff{%
  \expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@framestartpage}{}% does not happen normally
  {%else
    % removed \addtocontents commands
    \clearpage\beamer@notesactions%
  }
}
\newcommand*{\miniframeson}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson}
\newcommand*{\miniframesoff}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Introduction}

    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Outline}
        \tableofcontents[pausesections]
    \end{frame}

    \section{Context}
    % Slides of Context section
    \section{Development}
    % Slides of Development section
    \section{Results}
    \frame{}
    % Slides of Development section
    \miniframesoff
        \section{}
    \begin{frame}{Conclusion}

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

`\section*{sec_name}` prevents that section from appearing in the ToC, but it will still show in the Navigation Bar. If you don't want it in the Navigation Bar either, then simply don't use a `\section` command, just put the info in the frames.

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    %\section*{Introduction}

    \begin{frame}{Introduction}
        This is the intro
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Outline}
        \tableofcontents[pausesections]
    \end{frame}

    \section{Context}
    % Slides of Context section
    \section{Development}
    % Slides of Development section
    \section{Results}
    % Slides of Results section
    \begin{frame}{Results}
      This is the result.     
    \end{frame}

    %\section*{Conclusion}

    \begin{frame}{Conclusion}

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have thought to this option but it considers the Conclusion frames as Results frames, putting in the side bar that we are in the Result sections. It still not what I want

Comment: @Vavou That's because there was no Results frame in the MWE (if I understood correctly what you don't like). I updated the MWE in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still interested, you can hide the conclusion from appearing in the sidebar, by placing `\appendix` such as:

```
\section*{} 
\appendix
\begin{frame}{conclusion}
conclusion here
\end{frame}
```

Comment: This answer actually works. Thank you