# Removing the last bullet from the top navigation bar

Tags: beamer, navigation, mini-frames

I wish to remove the bullet corresponding to the last slide of my presentation from the top navigation bar, like this:

[image: What I want]

To that end, I've attempted to use an empty section `\section{}` as recommended in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317774/hide-section-from-sidebar).

**MCVE**

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usetheme[compress]{Singapore}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Introduction}
    \end{frame}

    \section{Section 1}
    \begin{frame}{Slide 1a}    
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}{Slide 1b}    
    \end{frame}

    \section{Section 2}
    \begin{frame}{Slide 2a}    
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}{Slide 2b}    
    \end{frame}

    \section{}
    \begin{frame}{Recapitulation}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But the unwanted bullet is still there:

[image: What I get]

How could I get around this?

Comment: Perhaps https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37127/how-to-remove-some-pages-from-the-navigation-bullets-in-beamer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**: The header would still be "focused" on the "section 2" text. To prevent this, I added `\section*{}` right after `\bulletoff`.

The "bullet system" is called `miniframes`, and are generated via a `.nav` file. The command responsible for writing to that file is the `\beamer@writeslidentry`. We can make this do *nothing* for a temporary amount of time:

```
\makeatletter
% Remember the way beamer did it before
\let\beamer@old@writeslidentry\beamer@writeslidentry
% Tell it to do nothing with the slides entry
\newcommand\bulletoff{\let\beamer@writeslidentry\relax}
% Reset it to the old ways
\newcommand\bulleton{\let\beamer@writeslidentry\beamer@old@writeslidentry}
\makeatother
```

Your entire code becomes then

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usetheme[compress]{Singapore}
\begin{document}
    \makeatletter
    % Remember the way beamer did it before
    \let\beamer@old@writeslidentry\beamer@writeslidentry
    % Tell it to do nothing with the slides entry
    \newcommand\bulletoff{\let\beamer@writeslidentry\relax}
    % Reset it to the old ways
    \newcommand\bulleton{\let\beamer@writeslidentry\beamer@old@writeslidentry}
  \makeatother
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Introduction}
    \end{frame}

    \section{Section 1}
     \begin{frame}{Slide 1a}
     \end{frame}
     \begin{frame}{Slide 1b}
     \end{frame}

    \section{Section 2}
     \begin{frame}{Slide 2a}
     \end{frame}
     \begin{frame}{Slide 2b}
     \end{frame}

     \bulletoff\section*{}
     \begin{frame}{Recapitulation}
      No bullet here :)
     \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This produces exactly the image you presented:

[image]

---

Note that if you use the `\bulleton` command, it will behave differently if you do `\clearpage` prior to it. If you don't do `\clearpage` the bullet will be filled.