# Beamer with Berlin theme: slide in "hidden" section appears in navigation bar

Tags: beamer

I am trying to achieve the same thing as in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317774/hide-section-from-sidebar) but using the Berlin theme, namely, I want to have a "Conclusion" slide at the end that does not appear in the top navigation panel.

By putting it in an empty-titled section as per the accepted answer I have succeeded in making it not appear as an additional slide in the last section. However, when the "Conclusion" slide is displayed, the navigation button to the *first* slide of the last section is highlighted (but the name of the section isn't). I would like to stop it, so that nothing in the top panel is highlighted when the "Conclusion" slide is displayed.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Introduction}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Outline}
        \tableofcontents[pausesections]
    \end{frame}

    \section{Context}
    \begin{frame}{Context}
    \end{frame}

    \section{Development}
    \begin{frame}{Development}
    \end{frame}

    \section{Results}
    \begin{frame}{Results}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}{More results}
    \end{frame}

    \section{}
    \begin{frame}{Conclusion}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berlin}

\makeatletter
\let\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson=\beamer@writeslidentry%
\def\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff{%
  \expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@framestartpage}{}% does not happen normally
  {%else
    % removed \addtocontents commands
    \clearpage\beamer@notesactions%
  }
}
\newcommand*{\miniframeson}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson}
\newcommand*{\miniframesoff}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Introduction}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Outline}
        \tableofcontents[pausesections]
    \end{frame}

    \section{Context}
    \begin{frame}{Context}
    \end{frame}

    \section{Development}
    \begin{frame}{Development}
    \end{frame}

    \section{Results}
    \begin{frame}{Results}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}{More results}
    \end{frame}

        \miniframesoff
    \section{}
    \begin{frame}{Conclusion}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```