# Exclude last slide and Appendix from miniframes

Tags: beamer, mini-frames

I am creating a presentation using the default beamer theme. I want the miniframes at the top of the slides to stop at the 'conclusion' slide. No miniframes should be shown for the 'thank you' slide and the appendix. Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439349/36296

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme{miniframes}

\makeatletter
\let\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson=\beamer@writeslidentry%
\def\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff{%
  \expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@framestartpage}{}% does not happen normally
  {%else
    % removed \addtocontents commands
    \clearpage\beamer@notesactions%
  }
}
\newcommand*{\miniframeson}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson}
\newcommand*{\miniframesoff}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    
\section{title}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Conclusions}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\miniframesoff
\begin{frame}
Thank you
\end{frame}

\appendix
\begin{frame}
appendix
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```